YouTube как расшифровать дату начала трансляции
Делаю парсер на Python, новичок в этом деле. Нужно брать название видео и дату начала предстоящей трансляции. На фото прикрепил, там startTime какое-то странное значение хранит, вот как его понять.

пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.

Не странное, вполне обычное число секунд, прошедшее с полуночи 1 января 1970 года

Unix Timestamp (1720072800 -> Thu Jul 04 2024 06:00:00 GMT+0000)

Обычный timestamp:
import datetime as dt

print(dt.datetime.fromtimestamp(1720072800))

# 2024-07-04 09:00:00

